# Ruby - Problems concatenating array elements within loop

Tags: ruby, for-loop

I'm very new to Ruby and am having some problems concatenating strings within a for loop.

Here is what I have so far

```
# search request
search = ["testOne", "testTwo"]

# Create base url for requests in loop
base_url = "http://example.com/"

# create an empty response array for loop below
response = []

search.each do |element|
  response = "#{base_url}#{element}"
end
```

I'd like response[0] to hold "http://example.com/testOne". However, after the loop executes, response[0] only holds the first letter (h) of my base variable; response holds "http://example.com/testTwo".

I'm thinking this is a simple mistake, but can't find any helpful resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) method

```
# search request
search = ["testOne", "testTwo"]

# Create base url for requests in loop
base_url = "http://example.com/"

# create an empty response array for loop below
response = []

search.each do |element|
  response << "#{base_url}#{element}"
end

response # => ["http://example.com/testOne", "http://example.com/testTwo"]
```

`response = "#{base_url}#{element}"` means you are assigning in each iteration a new string object to the **local variable** `response`. In the last iteration `response` holds the string object `"http://example.com/testTwo"`. Now `response[0]` means you are calling the method [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). So at **index** `0` of the string `"http://example.com/testTwo"`, the character present is `h`, so your `response[0]` returning `'h'`- which is expected as per your code.

The same code can be written in more sweet way :

```
# search request
search = ["testOne", "testTwo"]

# Create base url for requests in loop
base_url = "http://example.com/"

response = search.map {|element| base_url+element }
response # => ["http://example.com/testOne", "http://example.com/testTwo"]
```

or

```
response = search.map(&base_url.method(:+))
response # => ["http://example.com/testOne", "http://example.com/testTwo"]
```

or, as *Michael Kohl* pointed :

```
response = search.map { |s| "#{base_url}#{s}" }
response # => ["http://example.com/testOne", "http://example.com/testTwo"]
```

Comment: I would go with `map { |s| "#{base_url}#{s}" }` instead of using `String#+`. +1 nonetheless.